# How do I count inverted question marks?

Tags: php, utf-8

How do I count the number of times an inverted question mark occurs in a string?

If I have a random string I wish to count the ¿ character. How can I do this?

I know the unicode code is `U+00BF`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `echo substr_count($text, '¿')`

An intersting hack: because JSON directly supports the \uxxxx syntax the first thing that comes into my mind is:

```
$unicodeChar = '\u00BF';
echo substr_count($text, json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"'));
```

Comment: @PezCuckow  '¿' is not a true unicode character, it can be encoded using just one byte, specifically has the 168 decimal code, so you can use it with any PHP normal string functions.

Comment: Decimal code for ¿ is 194 for clarity. Using mb_substr_count() is much safer when looking for such unusual characters as they may come with other unicode characters which substr_count() won't handle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**substr_count()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) for that, like this:

```
$times = substr_count($text, '¿');
```

The **¿** character is an ASCII-extended valid character so you can use it with normal php string functions.

Comment: Same as Pez Cuckow did, '¿' is an unicode character so you should use mb_* functions. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: @S3Mi '¿' is Extended-Ascii http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII  , I repeat, it's not a multibyte character, you can use it with all PHP normal string functions.

Comment: @S3Mi echo substr_count('¿ one ¿ two ¿ three','¿'); //echoes 3

Comment: "The term extended ASCII (or high ASCII) describes eight-bit or LARGER character encodings". Try mixing your source text with other unicode characters and find out if it counts right.

Comment: The one who should try it is YOU, because it works WELL contrary to what you think.

Comment: echo substr_count('¿которой ¿суж¿дено', '¿'); //echoes 3

Comment: substr_count() will always work fine if you provide a single-byte char as the needle parameter. What is wrong is providing a multi-byte char as the needle parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [mb_substr_count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr-count.php)

Ex.:

```
$count = mb_substr_count($text, '¿');
```